# How to configure SpringMVC to get static resources when js and css are in the same directory?

Tags: spring-mvc

```
<mvc:resources location="/images/" mapping="/images/**"/>
<mvc:resources location="/css/" mapping="/css/**"/>
<mvc:resources location="/styles/" mapping="/styles/**"/>
<mvc:resources location="/js/" mapping="/js/**"/>
```

This is the basic configuration of springMVC in order to load static resources. Now there is a problem that a calendar plugin only need my importing js and when project deployed, the js code generate a css file in webapp/js/theme directory. 
When visiting the website, there is a 404 error of css. So how am I supposed to set this configuration to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try using below code :

```
<mvc:resources location="/" mapping="/resources/**"/>
```

If above solution doesn't work then use below code (adding classpath to load) :

```
<mvc:resources location="/, classpath:/META-INF/web-resources/" mapping="/resources/**"/>
```